# Chrome inject script into previous tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm working on a Chrome extension with a background.js file and a script.js file that injects a few elements into a page's DOM. When a user *navigates away* from tab, I'd like to inject the script.js file into the tab (now not visible) that the user just navigated away from. In other words, user switches from tab A to tab B, and script.js is injected into tab A.

I have code that injects the script.js file when the tab is updated, but it injects into the active tab rather than the tab that the user just navigated away from. Any ideas?

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function (tab) {
        injectScript(tab.id);
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, updatedTab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function (activeTabs) {
        var activeTab = activeTabs[0];
        if (activeTab == updatedTab) {
            injectScript(activeTab.id);
        }
    });
});

function injectScript(id) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {
            file: "script.js"
    }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If a user _navigates away_ from a page, that page is unloaded and no longer exists. If you meant tab _switching_, you should avoid the term "navigate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could save the id of the most recently activated tab in a global variable. And in onActivated, injectScript into that tab id, and update the variable with the id of the newly active tab.

Comment: That's actually just how I ended up fixing it! Pretty simple solution. Thanks!